# Openpyxl Insert Row While Pushing Down Background Color

Tags: python, openpyxl

Has anyone tried using the insert_rows function and seeing how the background colors get impacted? It completely messes it up. The background color doesn't get pushed down like it normally would if you were to insert a row in Excel naturally. Does anyone know how to deal with this? See images below for reference.

```
report = reportWB.active

report.insert_rows(12)
```

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: It looks like the row contains merged cells. If this is the case, you'll need to unmerge the range and then merge the appropriate new range.

Comment: @CharlieClark nothing is merged

Comment: Why don't you use `report.append`?

Comment: @tuurtje11 I'm not trying to add data to the end of the sheet. I want to add data after a specific row number

Comment: Am I gonna have to loop through the whole sheet and check if the background color isn't white and then transfer the color down?